# ldapadd auto generated comments contain broken characters

Tags: openldap, ldif, phpldapadmin

I have an issue with an ldap entry. I try to create a dn such as :

```
dn: ou=élèves,ou=1A,ou=Classes,ou=Personnes,dc=ldap,dc=ecoleplurielle,dc=local
```

as I have utf-8 characters in `ou=élèves` I translate this value in base-64 and add an extra colon after the dn, which gives me :

```
dn::b3U9w6lsw6h2ZXMsb3U9MlNBLG91PUNsYXNzZXMsb3U9UGVyc29ubmVzLGRjPWxkYXAsZGM9ZWNvbGVwbHVyaWVsbGUsZGM9bG9jYWw=
```

The thing is when I use `ldapadd` with this entry, the command seems to auto generate comments and in this autogenerated comment, utf-8 characters a wrongly represented.

Let's see in details:

My ldapsearch result gives me this. You can see that the third comment starts by `\C3\A9` and `\C3\A8` which are hex values for utf-8 letters `é` and `è`.

[image]

[image]

On this image you can see the ldif used to populate ldap.

The weird thing is I do not write comments in the ldif file. The buggy line seems to appear on its own. You'd say it doesn't matter as it's just a comment but it makes phpLDAPadmin crash...

I already tried to convert the ldif in utf-8 using iconv.

Do someone know how to prevent this comment from being generated? Is there something I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable comments in the ldif output of [`ldapsearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) using the `-L` option :

> Search results are display in LDAP Data Interchange Format detailed in
> ldif(5). A single `-L` restricts the output to LDIFv1. A second `-L`
> disables comments. A third `-L` disables printing of the LDIF version.
> The default is to use an extended version of LDIF.

```
ldapsearch -LL [options]
```

Note that instead of turning whole dn string into base64, you could write accented characters as printable ASCII by escaping the hex pair given by their UTF-8 encoding, as specified by [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt) :

```
Unicode Letter Description        UCS code   UTF-8    Escaped
-------------------------------   --------   ------   --------
Latin Small Letter E with Acute   U+00E9     0xC3A9   \C3\A9
Latin Small Letter E with Grave   U+00E8     0xC3A8   \C3\A8
```

Which indeed turns the dn into :

```
dn: ou=\C3\A9l\C3\A8ves,ou=1A,ou=Classes,ou=Personnes,dc=ldap,dc=ecoleplurielle,dc=local
```

It would be interesting to check whether phpLDAPadmin has a problem with this encoding, or if the crash was caused by the base64 encoded dn or something else (I would be glad to have your feedback!).

---

[Edit] - It seems related to this [issue](https://github.com/leenooks/phpLDAPadmin/issues/132).

Comment: It doesn't seem phpLDAPadmin has any issue managing b64 encoded values.
I have attributes which have b64 encoded strings as value and are rendered by phpLdapadmin.
When I try to use the escaped values for accented letters it crashes. The values are recognized as é and è by openldap as they are correctly translated to b64 values. But when I reload phpldapadmin display it crashes. 

My issue remain. How to prevent phpLDAPpadmin to try to render such unicode values? I tried editing phpldapadmin config.php to use -LL and get rid of them but could not find how. Any ideas?

Comment: So it seems it does not support escaped utf-8 at some point. Though I don't think the generated comment causes the issue, but rather just the fact that the dn contains an escaped sequence. PLA must handle it before even writing it down as a comment or anything. Having it represented as dn: <string> or dn:: <base64(string)> should not make a difference. In the meantime, I found an issue on PLA's repo which seems to be related to yours (if not exactly the same), you might want to check it, @see the link above.